Is there a reason why my system isn't running command lines tools?
I have downloaded and installed command line tools two times but my system is saying I should still install it

I have downloaded it on Android Studio and also separately on the website but it still not working when I run on my system.  Please What do I need to do?

If you first solve the others issues and after it try to solve the cmd lines tools?

Please avoid using images to present your log message output. But copy that message and paste it into SO. Also, please use proper formatting for it.

Screenshots don't count towards satisfying [mre] requirements for the reasons given in Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question? -- please [edit] the question and replace the screenshot with a textual transcript.

I've updated my answer to clarify something.

There are two exceptions in your environment:
The first one is to properly install your cmdline-tools
and the second one is you need to accept Android's SDK licenses.
To resolve it,
In your Android Studio (by the way, I am using Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1)
Go to Tools > SDK Manager > (In Android SDK) > SDK Tools (tab) and check it if you already installed this, if yes, update it by clicking on its check box icon (but technically it is not check box icon, but - instead, because it has a pending latest version):
Try these:

Then, as the log message suggests:
Open your terminal in your Android Studio and execute this command to accept SDK licenses:
flutter doctor --android-licenses

Then instead of using flutter doctor, use flutter doctor -v command to see the detailed information about your environment.
If the issue persist,
Try, File > Invalidate Caches...
and after the Android Studio restarted, perform flutter doctor -v again.
Please read this to learn more about Command-line tools
Let me know if it resolves your issue.
UPDATE
Here's the direct-to-the-point answer to the question of the OP: link. I'm also quoting the statement from the given link.
Is says:

cmdline-tools component is missing
What does this issue look like?
The flutter doctor command complains that the cmdline-tools are
missing from the Android toolchain. For example:
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2) 
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk 
    X cmdline-tools component is missing

Explanation and suggestions
The easiest way to get the cmdline-tools is through the SDK Manager in
Android Studio. To do this, use the following instructions:
Open the SDK Manager from Android Studio, by selecting Tools > SDK
Manager from the menu bar. Select the latest Android SDK (or a
specific version that your app requires), Android SDK Command-line
Tools, and Android SDK Build-Tools. Click Apply to install the
selected artifacts.

If you're not using Android Studio, you can download the tools using
the sdkmanager command-line tool.

I hope it helps!

Thank you for your response, I've done that, still not working, downloaded all SDK Tools available and update them to the latest, it's still the same when I ran on my terminal, it stated I still need to download and install command line tools.

Have you already read this Command-line tools?

Yes I have read that
